# Regularly seeing PG::InFailedSqlTransaction error when deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Whenever we deploy our Rails/Postgres app and a migration is part of the deploy we get the following error:

> PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted,
>   commands ignored until end of transaction block
>
> PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR: cached plan must not change result
>   type

The offending SQL transaction is usually different.

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent this from happening when we deploy?

Answer (score 2):

### Cause:

Prepared statements are cashed in order to improve performance.
Whenever a prepared statement is used after the schema of an involved table has been changed, you get:

```
PG::FeatureNotSupported: ERROR: cached plan must not change result type
```

PG's adapter usually recovers from this by gracefully [`DEALLOCATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-deallocate.html)ing the prepared statement.

However, if the error happens in a transaction, the transaction would have already failed. The `DEALLOCATE` statement is ran inside the same transaction and therefore is rolled back.
So the connection is left with a cashed prepared statement that doesn't work.

### Solutions:

- Upgrade to Rails 5.0.4+ as the issue is resolved [there](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22170).
- Don't have any rails processes running while you run migrations. Not applicable if you want zero downtime deploys. Applicable, but inconvenient if you have multiple applications accessing the same databse.
- [Disable prepared statements](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-postgresql-database) altogether. May or may not cause a performance hit:

  ```
  # config/database.yml

  production:
    prepared_statements: false
  ```
- Add the [following monkey patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12330#issuecomment-244930976) to `ActiveRecord::Base` (slightly modified version):

  ```
  # config/initializers/rails_recoverable_transactions.rb

  raise "Remove monkey patch in #{__FILE__}" if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR > 4

  module TransactionRecoverable
    module ClassMethods
      def transaction(*args)
        super(*args) do
          yield
        end
      rescue PG::InFailedSqlTransaction
        connection.rollback_db_transaction
        connection.clear_cache!

        super(*args) do
          yield
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class << ActiveRecord::Base
    prepend TransactionRecoverable::ClassMethods
  end
  ```

This makes sure that if you get said error in a transaction, the transaction is closed first, then the cache is cleared and then the transaction is retried once. If for some reason you don't want to retry transactions you can remove the `super` call inside the `rescue` block.

Comment: thanks for the answer, if I didn't want to retry and instead raise should i replace the super call inside the rescue block with a raise or is that not needed?

Comment: @flylib Indeed, if you want to raise just replace the `super` call with the relevant `raise`.